# Google Analytics V2 IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I am getting the following exception (very rarely) using GA V2.  I can't find anything on the net about it at all.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tracker closed
at     com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GoogleTracker.assertTrackerOpen(GoogleTracker.java:60)
at     com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GoogleTracker.trackView(GoogleTracker.java:108)
at     myapp.Analytics.startGame(Analytics.java:53)
```

I have the following calls, both made by the game's update thread, and not the original activity's thread:

```
public void startTracker() {
    analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(activity.getApplicationContext());
    tracker = analytics.getTracker("XX-XXXXXXXXX-X");
    tracker.setStartSession(true);
}

public void startGame() {
    tracker.trackView("new_game");
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here or do I just need to catch the exceptions and ignore them?